# Exiting terminal running "nohup ./my_script &" => "You have running jobs". OK to exit?

Tags: zsh, background-process, nohup

Say I run the following on a remote box with the idea of preventing killing the job when I disconnect the terminal.

```
nohup ./my_script.sh &
```

When I try to exit my terminal, I got the following warning:

```
zsh: you have running jobs
```

I presume that's ok. It's just telling me that I have a job / process running in the background. If I disconnect the terminal, the job/process will continue to run, correct?

Comment: I found that zsh's nohup is broken and doesn't do what you want. Disown works most of the time. Though once I had an issue trying to use disown with ffmpeg in zsh, so started a bash shell and ran nohup inside that.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Yeah, that's fine. The child process will receive a HUP signal, but the process won't die thanks to your `nohup`.

If you want to not see that message, simply pass the job id to `disown`, like so:

```
disown %1
```

Or, start the job with `&!` (zsh-specific trick):

```
nohup ./my_script.sh &!
```

Comment: Can the `&!` trick work on the bash as well?